# sccm 2012 task sequence not running a exe or hta

Tags: sccm

I am trying to run a EXE or HTA file from command line, all it is, is a popup message that informs the end users of what is about to be deployed. I am run it from command line locally and it works great, but when I set it up as a task sequence it will not run.

Comment: Please provide a description of how you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined the log file smsts.log?

Run the HTA using a Run Command Line step.

Here is an example: %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\mshta.exe %ScriptRoot%\MyCustomHTA.hta

You could refer to the sample from here.

[HTA in SCCM Task Sequence](https://trevorsullivan.net/2009/08/25/hta-in-sccm-task-sequence/)